# How to construct an iterator class?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I wish to understand the following [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/) of an iterator class. What does `input_iterator_tag` do? Is `mit.p` used as a value used in the constructor, but isn't `mit.p` a pointer? What is `*this`? If the constructor allows only integer and pointer/value reference, is `myiterator beginning(numbers)` allowed?

```
// iterator example
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

class myiterator : public iterator<input_iterator_tag, int>   // what is input_iterator_tag?
{
  int* p;
public:
  myiterator(int* x) :p(x) {}
  myiterator(const myiterator& mit) : p(mit.p) {}  // why isn't this p(*mit.p)?
  myiterator& operator++() {++p;return *this;}   // what is *this?
  myiterator operator++(int) {myiterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
  bool operator==(const myiterator& rhs) {return p==rhs.p;}
  bool operator!=(const myiterator& rhs) {return p!=rhs.p;}
  int& operator*() {return *p;}
};

int main () {
  int numbers[]={10,20,30,40,50};
  myiterator beginning(numbers);   // however, constructor is not overloaded with array
  myiterator end(numbers+5);
  for (myiterator it=beginning; it!=end; it++)
      cout << *it << " ";
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the order that you asked them, the answers to your questions are:

1) `input_iterator_tag` is explained here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Thus, `myiterator` extends `iterator` and specifies (at compile time) that it is an **input** iterator. It also specifies that the type it iterates over is `int`. (Caveat: this is the answer I'm least sure about, since I'm not hugely experienced with templates and iterators.)

2) Yes, `mit.p` is a pointer, but so is `p`, so `p` (the pointer) is being initialized as a copy of `mit.p` (also a pointer). Therefore they both point to the same memory location.

3) `*this` is the iterator itself. That is, `this` is a pointer to whatever actual iterator object is calling the method using `this`, so `*this` is the actual value of that object: the iterator itself.

4) Arrays can be treated as pointers in C++: a variable holding an array behaves essentially the same as a pointer to the first element in the array. Thus it is legal to pass an array argument instead of a pointer argument.